# how to find in between Ou=9999998 Only number

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to find substring (`Ou=9999998` only number) from string?

For example, suppose this is my string:

```
string myString = "cn=54445sddsfsd,ou=9998fgfgfgf8855,o=fgfgfdg,u=dfddfgfgg,subject=5454gffdgfg454‌​hg";
```

I want to only `99988855`

Comment: I think you should put little bit more effort to format and better explain your question...also (according to [help]) you should describe what you tried and what you expect (here I just see your requirement...)

Comment: You could use either a regex to find the right part, or use string manipulation to split the string into pieces and get your "ou"-part.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest converting the `string` to *dictionary* with a help of *Linq*:

```
  using System.Collections.Generic; // for Dictionary
  using System.Linq;                // Linq: ToDictionary
  ...

  String source = 
    "cn=54445sddsfsd,ou=99988855,o=fgfgfdg,u=dfddfgfgg.subject=5454gffdgfg454hg";

  Dictionary<String, String> data = source
    .Split(',')
    .ToDictionary(line => line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf('=')),
                  line => line.Substring(line.IndexOf('=') + 1));
```

then get the value

```
  // "99988855"; you may want to put int.Parse(data["ou"]); if you want integer value
  String result = data["ou"];
```

or check if there's value and get it if it is:

```
  String result;

  if (data.TryGetValue("ou", out result)) {
    // "ou" key found
  }
  else {
    // no "ou" key found
  }
```

Comment: Dictionary not found

Comment: @appy: please, ensure that you have `using System.Collections.Generic;` as well as `using System.Linq; `

Comment: dim strArray,ouStr,cert,sr
  strArray = split(cert,",")
  srt = split(cert," ")
  for i=0 to ubound(strArray)
    if instr(strArray(i),"CID")>0 then
      ouStr = strArray(i)
    end if
  next please this code transfer into asp.net with c#

Comment: dictionary not found if i use other string

Answer (score 0):

Try this way you will get all the number part from this string after equal to symbol in an arry.

```
string myString = "cn=54445sddsfsd,ou=99988855,o=fgfgfdg,u=dfddfgfgg,subject=5454gffdgfg454hg";
    string[] myArray= myString.Split(',');
    string[] finalOutPut = (from item in myArray
                where Regex.IsMatch(item.Substring(item.LastIndexOf('=') + 1), @"^\d+$")
                select item.ToString()).ToArray<string>();
```

In this code the array finalOutput will have one value ie) ou=99988855.

Comment: : 'char' does not contain a definition for 'Substring' and no extension method 'Substring' accepting a first argument of type 'char' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Not specify location all Time Ou So we not use +1

Comment: string myString = "cn=54445sddsfsd,ou=9998fgfgfgf8855,o=fgfgfdg,u=dfddfgfgg,subject=5454gffdgfg454hg";
 now How to find

Comment: I am getting the right answer that's why I've posted this answer here. Actually I never face such an error while I am complied or run. Any way let me check once more.

Comment: Yes Sir But no pass this type vale ou=9998fgfgfgf8855

Comment: You do one thing, pls update your question and make some clarity, Otherwise no one can give you the answer which you are expecting.

Comment: dim strArray,ouStr,cert,sr
  strArray = split(cert,",")
  srt = split(cert," ")
  for i=0 to ubound(strArray)
    if instr(strArray(i),"CID")>0 then
      ouStr = strArray(i)
    end if
  next please this code transfer into asp.net with c#

Comment: dictionary  not found if i use other string